# Pandas select and write rows that contain certain text

Tags: python, pandas

I want to keep only rows in a dataframe that contains specific text in column `"col"`. In this example either `"WORD1"` or `"WORD2"`.

```
df = df["col"].str.contains("WORD1|WORD2")
df.to_csv("write.csv")
```

This returns `True` or `False`. But how do I make it write entire rows that match these critera, not just present the boolean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is returned is a boolean series you use that to filter the df:

```
df = df[df["col"].str.contains("WORD1|WORD2")]
```

You can then write this out as normal:

```
df.to_csv("write.csv")
```

Example:

```
In [14]:    
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['word', 'WORD1', 'WORD2', 'WORD3']})
df

Out[14]:
     col
0   word
1  WORD1
2  WORD2
3  WORD3

In [15]:    
df[df['col'].str.contains('WORD1|WORD2')]

Out[15]:
     col
1  WORD1
2  WORD2
```

Comment: Yes I corrected that in my working example but not the initial answer, but it's corrected now. You should always treat the boolean series as a mask to use against the original series/df